# Another word for the "about" section of a personal website

Tags: word-choice

The word that I'm looking for was frequently used as a means to communicate that there would be biographical or site based information via the link of that word.

I can't recall the word, something that ended in -phile, -phone, -gram or something of that nature. It could have began with homo-. (All of those are likely completely innacurate but for some reason at the tip of my tongue)

Does anyone recall this word?

Comment: Because of the past tense "was", I assume you want us to tell you a word that often used to be used as the label for a link to a profile page or to a site map, but no longer is used for that purpose.  Is that a correct summary of your question?

Comment: Yes, I used to see it on blogs ~2000-2005, but it has since been replaced largely by "about" and its variants. But it was usually biographical or about the site itself. Containing information like the technology used to run the site, credits, or information about the writer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is:

> [***colophon***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/colophon): *A page on a website identifying the details of its creation, such as the author's name and the technologies used.*

Comment: Yes! That's it. How did you find it!? Every google search I tried returned garbage (poor search terms on my part).

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen- Didn't find it on the internet- I happened to be staring at an O'Reilly book at the time and then did a direct search to verify its internet usage.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen a geeky example http://lanyrd.com/colophon/