# Alternatives to the term "about me"

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

I'm looking for an alternative to the term "about me".

It's for a navigation entry on a website and I'm tired to see "about me" everywhere on the web.

As I'm not native speaking english (german) it is quite difficult to find another term. Even though in german it is not easy to find one.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The question mentioned in the "This is a duplicate" section ["Another word for the “about” section of a personal website"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/another-word-for-the-about-section-of-a-personal-website) is different. What I'm looking for are synonyms, other words for the meananing of "about me". I just mentioned the website navigation to make clear that it's not used in a entence or text.

Comment: The thing is, *about me* is a very good contraction of the instruction *click here to read details about me* and web users understand it very well. You could try *my details* but (especially if your web page is public) it's best to use terms with which people are familiar.

Comment: Hi @Daenu please give examples of where you need to use a replacement for 'about me'. Thanks.

Comment: How about "Who am I?"

Comment: @JulieCarter As I said it's for a navigation (menu) entry on a website. On that page I'm talking about my work, my skills, etc

Comment: We need to see examples of phrases where you have put 'about me', to see what words would fit. Please give more detail, or your question may be closed for being unclear. Thanks, @Daenu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Another word for the "about" section of a personal website](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/another-word-for-the-about-section-of-a-personal-website)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen the following as alternatives to “about me”: profile, biography, bio, my story, portrait, resume

Rather than just having one page, I have also seen some of these grouped together into subpages.  For example, a master “bio” page with subpages including: about, resume, projects, client comments.  It will depend on what kind of content you want to create, what information you want to share, the online format in which you wish to share it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about altenative words not alternative mechanisms of creating a website.

Comment: Thank you. That already gives me a good idea. I think I'll opt for "portrait"

Comment: @Chenmunka I think it answers the question quite well though

Comment: @Chenmunka  My understanding is that the site is about English Language & Usage.  While this was a search for synonyms, a mere listing of thesaurus entries would not address the functional context in which the synonym would be used.  The word has to fit the context, yes?  Daenu was quite specific about the context of his/her usage needs, and I felt it warranted a targeted approach.  I also appreciated the other usage-oriented comments and answers here specific to the question.

Comment: I needed a shorter version of About me for small screens, so Bio fits the bill. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this

- Hey it's "Your name" and then the description.
- you can also write "About the author" and then write in third person(first person also works).
- you can also twist the above line with "know thy author" with a witty touch.
- Some people put a tab "bio/biography" to tell about them.
- you can also do a "knock,knock" :-p